# Get start date and end date assuming sunday as first date of the week in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create 2 columns: `startdate` & `enddate` with Sunday as first date of the week.

Here is the script

```
SELECT 
    MyDate,
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST([MyDate] AS date)) AS WEEDAY,
    DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST([MyDate] AS date))), CAST([MyDate] AS date)) StartDate,
    DATEADD(D, (6 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST([MyDate] AS date))), CAST([MyDate] AS date)) EndDate
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    MyDate  BETWEEN '2024-02-04' AND '2024-02-10'
ORDER BY 
    MyDate
```

But I don't get the desired results.

Sunday 4 should falls in the 4-10 week.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the result]

I've tried to change the `@@datefirst` but I got same results.

Can you help please?

Thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgresql, etc.)

Comment: The `CAST()` makes me sad. It tells us you're storing the date values as varchar instead of  date or datetime, which is more than a little bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `StartDate`, it's simpler to use modulo 7 of the weekday and for `EndDate`, just add six days to `StartDate`:

```sql
SELECT
MyDate,
DATEPART(WEEKDAY, cast([MyDate] as date)) AS WEEDAY,
DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, cast([MyDate] as date)) % 7), cast([MyDate] as date)) StartDate,
DATEADD(D, 6, DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, cast([MyDate] as date)) % 7), cast([MyDate] as date))) EndDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDate  BETWEEN '2024-02-04' AND '2024-02-10'
ORDER BY MyDate
```

Comment: 'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name. I'm using SQL SERVER.

Comment: Use `%` operator instead. I've updated my answer code snippet. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16